# First time using d3 and rawgit and it seemed to have stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

So I'm new to javascript and I was working on slightly modifying code from here https://github.com/virajsanghvi/d3.basketball-shot-chart

It was working just a few weeks ago, but I went to check now and not even the example is working. I think the problem is when it tries to add http://rawgit.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.js as an src to the document, since that link no longer works. There is a d3 in the directory, but using ../d3.js in place of the above URL did not work for me.

If anyone could point me in the correct direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You mean `./d3.js` ? This is the correct form if it's in the same directory

Comment: No, sorry, it's in the parent directory

Comment: the "official" link according to documentation is the following: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: that worked! I had just tried it without the charset, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The correct form to access D3 is the following:

```
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This is the link to the `v3`: `v4` is available but not yet stable (at the time of this writing, obviously).

The `utf-8`charset is necessary, either here or in the page header,  to avoid an error with `pi`. See the documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki#installing